# Ubuntu Pro Purchase Problem

Tags: ubuntu-pro

I have been trying to buy a subscription to Ubuntu Pro since Monday.  No matter the option or the selection, the "Next Step" box is still greyed out.  I have used Google Chrome, Firefox and Opera to no avail.
PS - Take my money!

Comment: Connect Canonical. We can't help you with that.

Comment: We are users like you. We can't take your money.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about Ubuntu software, but instead Canonical's sales website.  There is no mechanism for Ask Ubuntu to support this, so your only option is to reach out to Canonical Sales or Support for assistance.

Comment: For better or worse, this was a broadcast where I asked the same question over every point where they might be able to answer.  I recognize that this is users, I have been unable to get any answers from any of the other ways I have tried to contact them.  While I am not proud to ask this question, it amazes me that Canonical has successfully ignored me, whe I am trying to give them money.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu Pro has its own [site](https://ubuntu.com/pro/tutorial) and at the bottom (see the "next steps")    it has a [contact us](https://ubuntu.com/contact-us/form?product=pro) and a link to [Ubuntu Pro Discourse](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/c/ubuntu-pro/?_ga=2.64549295.1015092190.1675969868-1749291643.1650826331).

It is not likely that you will get an official answer from Canonical or someone in charge for Ubuntu Pro as most of us are regular users. The 2 links  will get you to an answer.

Comment: All of those routes were tried before asking here.  Thanks anyways.